# Jquery: how can i "fire" an event?

Tags: jquery

i have a `<div>` that contains several elements; i've added a link with which the user can open and close the div container and it runs fine.
I would like to close that container also when the user clicks another item, so i would like to trigger the open/close i've defined simulating the click in the open/close link but it does not run.

```
html code:
<div id=container_expand_collapse>Open-close</div>
<div id=project_div_container>

    <div class=element>Element1</div>
   ....
</div>

JQuery code:

$('#container_expand_collapse').toggle(function() {
      $('#project_div_container').animate({width: 10});
   }, function() {
      $('#project_div_container').animate({width: 120});
   }
);

$(".element").click(function() {
   $("#container_expand_collapse").trigger("toggle");
}
```

How can i force the toggle event?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

better way

```
$('#container_expand_collapse, .element').live('click',function() {
      $('#project_div_container').animate({width: 10});
   }, function() {
      $('#project_div_container').animate({width: 120});
   }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

To trigger the `.click` on `$(".element")`, just do like this:
`$('.element').click()`

Answer (score 2):

toggle() is a helper function. You have to use click().

```
$(".element").click(function() {
    $("#container_expand_collapse").trigger("click");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine.  The toggle event is actually based off of the 'click' event, so you just have to change it to that.

```
$(".element").click(function() {
   $("#container_expand_collapse").trigger("click");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/Gaz2m/

Answer (score 1):

use `toggle` like

```
$("#container_expand_collapse").toggle( fn, fn2, [fn3,fn4,...]);
```

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EKesD/1/

http://docs.jquery.com/A